# Production planner

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, reference

I have a class that creates an object, `PlannedYear`, and then passes that object into several other classes to manipulate it. The ultimate goal of the class is to manipulate and add items to this `PlannedYear` object.

I have, however, ended up going down a rabbit hole whereby I am updating the same `PlannedYear` object in memory in multiple classes, rather than having methods with return types and so on.

Can anyone look at my code and advise me if I can (or if I even need to) get out of the rabbit hole? I have simplified the code to demonstrate the issue and added comments.

**EDIT:** The overall purpose of the code is to read an existing production plan from a database, then take new items (stored in `Estimate` objects) and schedule them on top.

**Planner.cs:**

```
public class Planner
{
    // This object ends up getting modified all over the place
    // Ultimately it is this YearPlan that is the output of this class
    public PlannedYear YearPlan { get; private set; } 

    private PlanReader planReader = new PlanReader();

    public Planner()
    {
        YearPlan = planReader.GetExistingScheduleFromDatabase();
    }

    public void Plan(List<Estimate> estimates)
    {
        foreach (var estimate in estimates.OrderBy(x => x.Priority))
        {
            // Here's the start of the issue. YearPlan passed into a scheduler and gets modified
            var scheduler = new EstimateScheduler(estimate, YearPlan); 
            scheduler.Schedule();
        }
    }
}
```

**EstimateScheduler.cs:**

```
public class EstimateScheduler
{
    private PlanSearcher planSearcher;
    private Estimate estimateToSchedule;

    public EstimateScheduler(Estimate estimate, PlannedYear yearPlan)
    {
        estimateToSchedule = estimate;
        // yearPlan passed into planSearcher
        planSearcher = new PlanSearcher(yearPlan, 
                                        estimateToSchedule.StartDate, 
                                        estimateToSchedule.EndDate);
    }

    public void Schedule()
    {
        foreach (var itemHeader in estimateToSchedule.ItemHeaders)
        {
            ScheduleItemHeader(itemHeader);
        }
    }

    private void ScheduleItemHeader(EstimateItemHeader itemHeader)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemHeader.EstimateItems)
        {
            if (!planSearcher.DoesABedBigEnoughForThisItemExist(item.Length, item.Width))
            {
                HandleItemThatCannotBePlanned(item); // Not important
            }
            else
            {
                var canItemBeAddedToBed = true;
                while (item.HasItemsRemainingToBeScheduled && canItemBeAddedToBed)
                {
                    // get a bed from planSearcher (which searches yearPlan) and try to add an item to it
                    var bed = planSearcher.FindBedSpaceForItem(item);
                    if (bed != null)
                    {
                        bed.AddItem(item); // Updates the actual bed object which persists in planSeacher
                        item.ItemsScheduled++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        canItemBeAddedToBed = false;
                        HandleItemThatCannotBePlanned(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PlanSearcher.cs:**

```
public class PlanSearcher
{
    private List<PlannedDay> plannedDays;

    public PlanSearcher(PlannedYear yearPlan, DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {
        // we take yearPlan and get only the range of days we need to modify
        plannedDays = yearPlan.PlannedDays.Where(x => x.Date >= start && x.Date <= end).ToList();
    }

    public PlannedBed FindBedSpaceForItem(IItem item)
    {
        // search this.plannedDays for a bed and return it
    }
}
```

**PlannedDay.cs:**

```
public class PlannedDay
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<PlanendBed> PlannedBeds { get; set; }

    public PlannedDay(DateTime date)
    {
        this.Date = date;
        this.PlannedBeds = new List<PlannedBed>();
    }
}
```

**PlannedYear.cs:**

```
public class PlannedYear
{
   public List<PlannedDay> PlannedDays { get; set; }

   public PlannedYear()
   {
      PlannedDays = new List<PlannedDay>();
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: @TobySpeight Hi Toby. I have edited the question to describe the overall purpose of the code is. I am not sure if I can add this to the title in a way that is clear and not confusing.